# What can cause a site to hang when deleting a user?

Tags: users, 7

When I try to delete users the whole site hangs, i.e. Drupal does not respond anymore. What can cause that?

The site does not have any special user profile modules installed.

**Edit:**
There is only one custom (self made) module with a hook_user which switches on `$op`. The 'delete' case looks unsuspicious:

```
case 'delete':
    $sql = "DELETE FROM {mynewsletter_users} WHERE uid = %d";
    db_query($sql, $account->uid);
    break;
```

Doesn't look bad to me. Should not invoke a hook_user-circle.

**Edit:**
The problem is gone all by itself. No idea what happened.

Comment: Check the recent logs and see if there's an error. It could be a database error, or possibly a php memory error. Is this on a local server or a hosted server?

Comment: I am afraid to get the site hanging again. That's why I cannot check right now (need to wait for a time of less activity). The site is hosted on a remote server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, this has happened when there is a misconfiguration on `hook_user` in a custom module. Specifically, check all of your implementations of `hook_user` to make sure there are no functions that lead to additional calls for `hook_user`.

That is, if you have a module that calls `foo_do_magic_to_user()` under `hook_user` (or, some other function that hits `hook_user`), and `foo_do_magic_to_user()` calls `user_save()`, then you have an infinite loop on your hands.

**Update**

If you're absolutely certain that it's not a `hook_user` loop, then there could be any number of module-associated hangups. These often involve external services that are non-responsive (e.g. sending a "Goodbye" email but sendmail (or equivalent) isn' set up properly).

In your shoes, I would try:

1) Disable all non-core modules and see if the problem persists. If this still happens with only core modules, then you might have a deeper and more fundamental issue (correct version of PHP?)

2) If not #1, then re-enable contrib modules one-by-one and see which one is causing the issue. Inspecting that module's hook_user should give you a good clue as to what the root issue is. Most likely, one of the modules is calling some other service that is non-responsive.

Comment: Updated the question...

Answer (score 2):

The very first thing I'd do is to set up a local VM with a replica of the live server for local testing. Ideally this would be a copy made with `dd` or similar.

See if anything is implementing `hook_user`. For D5-D6 sites I use a recursive grep (using [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/)) from the site root to locate these. Remove this code and see if the site still hangs.

Use the MySQL [Slow Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) to see if it has any hints. Use ps and top to see what's actually happening on the web server.

I don't think that D5 has locking (D6 has [lock_acquire](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--lock.inc/function/lock_acquire/6) in [lock.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--lock.inc/6))

It would also help if you could explain how you manage to recover the server once it's /locked/.